# PHP: Send Mail with Image Attachment Through Socket

Tags: php, email, attachment, send

I need to send an email with fsockopen that has one image attached. Until now I've used this code:

http://tareq.wedevs.com/2010/01/sending-mail-with-gmails-smtp-server-with-fsockopen/

which works great but doesn't embbed images. How can I do that?
I can't use any special extensions/libraries because I have no access to the server.

I have tried to just add

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,[IMAGE DATA] alt="IMG" />
```

but this doesn't seem to work (it always shows a broken image and the text "IMG"). I have the image date base64 encoded. Is there a better way to do that or would it be ok like this?
If it's ok like this, would you know why it might not work?

Answer (score 0):

PHP Mailer is the answer!

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

You can easily attach an image with this line:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment(base64_decode($IMG), "picture.jpg", "base64", "image/jpeg");
```